# Show a dialog asking users to be more specific if they use the phrase "didn't work" in a question

Tags: feature-request

It was occurring to me: using the phrase "didn't work" (as in "I tried this code but it didn't work") is virtually always terrible and indicative of a lousy question. So, if someone uses this phrase (or a variant), can they be shown a popup (or something similar) asking them to be more specific? Maybe even point them to How to Ask or the instructions on creating a MVCE.

Comment: What about cases where they write "didn't work because xyz". Seems needlessly intrusive for what I imagine would be a relatively small (if any) improvement in questions.

Comment: Or worst, when OP's really explaining that "I've tried using X but didn't work, changing to Y but still didn't fix the issue, setting the Z parameter also didn't help, lastly reinstalling Windows didn't solve it".

Comment: In addition, it won't help. Sure, there are lots of people who _do_ use "didn't work" without elaborating, but those are the kind of people who will simply dismiss the dialog and then write "won't work".

Comment: Yeah - probably won't help.  It requires effort to read the dialog and folllow any advice - something orthogonal to the objective of geting their homework done by someone else while putting in the least amount of effort themselves.  "Debugging?  That's hard work, debugger. logger, taking notes, drawing conclusions, testing them.  Stuff that -  I post to SO to get someone else to do the hard work!"

Comment: In a large number of cases, being this vague is quite intentional.  Carefully avoiding a trigger phrase that will get the question closed as a dup, like "nullpointerexception".  Or just generally pan for comments/answers to pick-and-choose from to get to the next step without having to do any real work.  Forcing such askers to post better documented questions won't work, they'll just find another way to be intentionally vague.  Just like banning "problem" did not work.  Better that you can instantly tell it will be a waste of your time.

Comment: In some cases the OP cannot comply with such suggestions because they have no clue whatsoever about the code they are posting.  It's stuff they downloadeded and posted, or it's stuff that some other student cooked up somehow and the OP has taken money to get it done.  It's just embarrassing when it becomes blatantly obvious that that the OP is totally incompetent, refusing even simple requests to format/indent code :((

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your basic idea isn't *wrong*.

People asking a hazy "didn't work" question is sometimes indeed down to a cultural misunderstanding rather than laziness. People (mostly non-technical ones) often confuse online media with how normal human conversations tend to work.

In a conversation, it is normal to start with something vague like "Hey, why does this thing not work?"

The addressee of the question will then ask "what do you mean?" and a back and forth will ensue, fleshing out more and more details, suggestions to fix, etc.

Of course, on Stack Overflow (and similar online places) this approach can only lead to catastrophe. You are expected to present a detailed case from the get go!

However, as was already discussed, showing some sort of pop-up would be unlikely to solve the problem:

- There'd be an awful lot of false positives
- A large portion of users either doesn't know how to go into any more detail than "didn't work" or can't be bothered to do so.

There's a lot of ways to get things wrong when starting things out on Stack Overflow, and if we had a popup for each of them, we'd have to have dozens.

Also, for anyone interested, there are plenty of good guides out there on how to ask a good Stack Overflow question.

Anyone worth their salt will quickly pick up on how things work in an online medium, and start asking better questions as a consequence, without needing our guidance.